# Adding layered navigation block to custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

In Magento, the Layered Navigation block works nicely in the product list page.

How can this block be successfully copied to a custom page, where there is a custom list of products?

Note: Just adding the block to the XML, and calling it's `getChildHtml('blockname')` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: You need to add a default category to the layared navigation block code as the layared navigation is build from the products of the current category.

Comment: +1 for the help, what if there are multiple products from multiple categories (for example, deal products)?

Comment: I'd make a special category for that. There might be other ways but this is definitely the easiest and most scalable one!

Comment: If you would really want to then you would have to create a custom category. The layered navigation really expects there to be a category to work with, it won't take a simple ProductCollection without overriding a whole lot of classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you have to do is **`extend/overwrite`** from **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List** `(List.php)` and rewrite the **`getProductCollection()`** method:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        // Build collection and set it
        $collection = "...";
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

When that was done I had overwritten both the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` class and the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` and introduced a new variable:

```
protected $_customProductCollection;
```

I have overwritten the **`getProductCollection()`** in both classes and I added this in the beginning of the method:

```
if(isset($this->_customProductCollection)){
    return $this->_customProductCollection;
}
```

I have also a method that allows me to set this **`"customProductCollection"`** inside both these classes. Once It's set, the rest of the data of the **layered navigation/category** is based on this collection.

Check out the initial question+answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726891/magento-layered-navigation-on-custom-product-collection).

Good luck ;)

Comment: What is this method to set customproductcollection and where do you call it from?