# layered navigation for custom product collection on custom page

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation

I'm working on a module where some products have an attribute named `designer`. and for every `designer`, all products by him displayed as `catalog category view`. So far I'm able to filter the products collection by `designer` attribute and successfully display them as the `catalog category view` page.

But now the problem is, I need to display a layered navigation for those product which may be filtered by price and all.

Is there a way that I could add layered navigation in that filtered product collection?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13/adding-layered-navigation-block-to-custom-page, http://blog.magestore.com/2012/06/29/magento-certificate-layered-navigation/

Comment: Why not use `designer` as a pre-set layered navigation option so the user can filter further with the default layered navigation

Answer (score 6):

**Mohammad found an answer on StackOverflow which has since been deleted. Here is that answer:**

Finally I found the solution for custom Layered navigation for custom product collection. Here are the changes what I have did to sort-out this issue.

**1.** Created one custom module for custom page. My custom page URL was http://{magento_root}/onsale

**2.** Set below Layout XML file for my custom page layout (`onsale` is my custom attribute)

```
<onsale_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="left">
       <block type="onsale/layer_view" name="customlayer" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="category.products" template="onsale/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="onsale/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</onsale_index_index>
```

**3.** In `onsale/category/view.phtml` I have just set page title & called  product listing `$this->getChildHtml('product_list');`.

**4.** Now I have three block file, a) **`onsale`**, b) **`product_list`**, c) **`layer_view`**.

a) `Mymodule_Onsale_Block_Onsale` extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` and it has just two method one for `_prepareLayout` & for `_prepareLayout`.

b) `Mymodule_Onsale_Block_Product_List` extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` and it has just one method which is as below:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{  

   if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) 
    {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();
        $productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

c) `layer_view` block has one method `getLayer()` as below:

```
public function getLayer()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('onsale/layer');
}
```

**5.** No changes in controller, just call to Layout & Render.

**6.** Now for model file. I have just one model file for layer with `getProductCollection` method as below which extend to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer`.

class name
   Mymodule_Onsale_Model_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer

```
  public function getProductCollection()
{

    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
        $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
    } else {

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('on_sale',array('eq'=>'125'));

        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

**7.** One last important, Please set `No` to `Use Flat Catalog Category` & `Use Flat Catalog Product` at `System -> configuration -> Catalog -> fontend`.

It show me correct product listing with layered navigation.

Comment: is 4 a) correct?  Also, what if one cannot set "use flat catalog category" to 'yes'?

Comment: I'm wondering about 4 a) also. Did you mean to say `_construct` and `_prepareLayout` or did you overwrite a different method than `_construct`?

Answer (score 1):

After digging a lot I'd found a working solution by [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206759/rakesh) on [<del>stackoverflow</del>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17947990/725306).

I'd recently seen that the answer on the link no longer available.

Comment: Can you please recreate the answer here

Comment: Answer was deleted. I'll post as a separate answer - Mohammad, feel free to grab the content and add it to your answer.