# Left layered navigation for the custom product collection in the custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, layered-navigation, custompage

I have a custom product collection (i.e) list of products which is based on the two attributes's values.
Page is replicating the catalog page by the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <customization_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customization/product_searchbycity" name="searchbycity" as="searchbycity" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

            </block>
        </reference>
        <!--<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>-->
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="customization/citysearch_layer" name="citysearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customization_index_index>
</layout>
```

Now I need the layered navigation in the left for the same collection. Below is the block.

```
<?php

class Probytes_Customization_Block_Citysearch_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        /* To get picked up by Mage_Catalog_Product_List::getLayer() */
        Mage::register('current_layer', $this->getLayer(), true);
    }

    public function getLayer()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('customization/citysearch_layer');
    }
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {  

       if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) 
        {
            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            $productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
            $this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

}
```

It's the model

class Probytes_Customization_Model_Citysearch_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
{

```
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
            //parent::prepareProductCollection($collection);
            //Mage::getModel('customization');
            $data['address'] = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('city-to-search');
            $model = Mage::getModel('customization/citysearch');
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
            //$collections = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
            $collection = $model->searchResult($data,$collection);
            return $this;
    }
    public function getProductCollection()
{

    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
        $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
    } else {

        $data['address'] = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('city-to-search');
            $model = Mage::getModel('customization/citysearch');
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
            //$collections = Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
            $collection = $model->searchResult($data,$collection);
    }
    return $collection;
} 

}
```

I tried like this
[layered navigation for custom product collection on custom page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17618/layered-navigation-for-custom-product-collection-on-custom-page)

But not working, I am getting empty array in the left navigation.